# Desktop Does Not Automatically Refresh When Moving/Renaming/Deleting Files & Folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop

When I create a new folder on the desktop and give it a name, the new name does not take effect until I manually refresh the desktop. The same thing happens when I try to delete it.

This behavior also applies to new `.txt` files, Word documents, Excel spreadsheets, etc.

Here is a GIF of it happening to a folder:

[image]

Comment: Tips:: Take ownership of C:\users\username\Desktop folder. Or delete desktop.ini file in Desktop folder. Or clean file history & file icon cache.

Comment: Took ownership and deleted the desktop.ini file but neither worked and file history is off: https://i.imgur.com/ZBAlacQ.png. Let me look at doing file icon cache and I'll let you know.

Comment: add these comments in your answer to show what you've tried to solve.

Comment: Does this happen if you perform a [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) of Windows?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Been happening to me for six months, all folders not just desktop. None of the answers made a jot of difference. Clean install of Windows 10 running on a VM on MacOS.

Comment: If it's occurring in other places, such as within Windows Explorer as well, then it's a known bug in Windows 10.  I have no idea how to solve it, but do know none of the answers below will fix the aforementioned.  As of Win10 v1909, the issue appears to no longer occur, so the inference is the bug was fixed either before, or in, v1909.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

**Settings > Personalization > Themes > Change desktop icons > Restore default**

If it cannot solve your issue, please also try to reset folder views:

[image: Screenshot]

Also go to `HKCR\CLSID\{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance` and change `DWORD` value **`DontRefresh`** from  `1` (on) to `0` (off).

Comment: So I tried both of your suggestions but it's still not working.

Reset Folders: https://i.imgur.com/BwUC2Rx.gif
Registry Edits: https://i.imgur.com/toLTS2L.mp4

The key you posted does not exist on my system. I added it myself per the advice of this article here: https://i.imgur.com/241Wmr4.png

Also based on the article the key you posted is for 32-bit systems whereas 64-bit systems is stored under HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\. Not that it matters since neither one works.

In case you're wondering I made sure to reboot my system before taking the video after I made those changes. No dice.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried this solution for your specific problem, but I'd consider it worth trying if I came up against your set of symptoms:

Save the following as a .bat file:

```
ie4uinit.exe -show
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
attrib -h iconcache_*.db
DEL /A /Q "%localappdata%\IconCache.db"
DEL /A /F /Q "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*"
start explorer
```

Save and close all files and programs, then run (it doesn't require admin).

When it completes restart your computer.

This script is for resetting desktop icon issues in Windows 10. Any shortcuts on your desktop should return to a default position to the upper-left of the primary screen.

Answer (score 2):

1. Settings > Personalization > Themes > Change desktop icons > Restore default
2. Uncheck *Allow themes to change desktop icons* > Apply > OK

If this does not work:

1. Restore default > check *Allow* again > Apply > OK
2. Go back in and Restore default > uncheck *Allow* again > Apply > OK

Unsure why I had to do this more than once, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a samba share to a network printer scan folder pinned in the quick access folder. After trying all other solutions including resetting my Windows, this worked! Look to see if you have any shortcuts to poor performing network locations.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @JW0914 this actually helped me.

Comment: @MaryPerret What helped you, as there's no answer in this answer? _(it's a comment to one of the other three answers existing as of 2017.03.17, posted as an answer because the user doesn't have enough rep to comment)_

Comment: @JW0914 the samba shared folder was actually preventing my UI from being refreshed accordingly whenever the was a change (folders or files that have just been moved or deleted).

Comment: @MaryPerret Was it the share itself or that it was pinned to Quick Access? _(If the latter, as currently worded, this answer is still just a reply to another answer and not an answer in and of itself, listing no way to resolve the issue)_ "_I had a samba share to a network printer scan folder pinned in the quick access folder... Look to see if you have any shortcuts to poor performing network locations._" What is supposed to done after looking for poor performing network locations? The author provides a stream of thought, but no actual [answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, the only thing I had to do was reboot and it refreshed when moving/renaming/deleting files & folders.

Comment: Sorry, for giving my answer so late, this happened to me recently and just wanted to share what happened with me, and hope it help anyone in the future if they have similar problems

Answer (score 0):

It took me forever to find out the fix to this issue, and I was tempted to just reset my whole PC, with the only thing stopping me being a slow connection. Thank you, Joan, for [your answer](//superuser.com/a/1264356) which give me an idea of how to fix it.

---

Here's how I finally got it:

After I went to Settings > Personalization > Themes > Desktop Icon Settings, I received a message saying something like `You do not have the permission to access this file` and `rundll32.exe` was listed in the top bar.

I went to `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe` and followed this procedure:

- Right-click `rundll32.exe` > select Properties > Security tab > Advanced.
- Click "Change", beside the "Owner" line of text, and change this to your user name.
- To close all the security and properties tabs: Apply > Accept everything > OK
- Right-click `rundll32.exe` > Properties > Security > Advanced > Enable inheritance
- Apply > accept everything > OK
- Once out of the Security and Properties tabs, close Explorer window > Restart PC

Upon restart, your auto-update should be working again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Folder Options
2. Untick the two Quick Access options within the General tab under Privacy
3. Click Clear File Explorer History

Answer (score 0):

[Switching](https://www.austintechnology.com.au/log-windows-10-without-microsoft-account/) from a cloud-synced Microsoft account to a local user account worked for me.

- If doing so, you may want to [remove](https://pureinfotech.com/delete-windows-10-settings-synced-microsoft-account/) your synced Win10 data from the MS servers